# Change pages during an ajax file upload

Tags: ajax, file-upload

I am currently uploading multiple videos on a page within my site using HTML5 file uploading, and allowing the user to fill in information about those videos.

The problem is that the videos can take a while to upload, and the users do not want to have to sit on the page waiting for the files to upload, they want to continue using the site, and are not at all competent enough to manage using two browser windows, or even two tabs at the same time.

Is it possible to prevent an ajax call from being cancelled when a page is changed? or change a page in such a way that the ajax upload call would continue?

Comment: OMG! I answered 6 minutes after you asked, and you just accepted my answer... almost 7 years later!? Unbelievable! ;)

Comment:  i was going through some of my old questions to see what i had previously asked, and saw that i hadnt accepted the answer on some of them. so thought it was right thing to do to accept the right answers 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to update the page via ajax while uploading a file but you'll have to implement that behavior by hand.
Add event listeners to the links supposed to update the page and override the browser's default behavior to send ajax requests and update the page accordingly.

If you use jQuery, the ajax method will suit your needs.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

To keep navigation consistent you should also implement an ajax history solution (so the users can use the browser's "previous" and "next" buttons.

you can use the jQuery.address plugin
http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Cheers and happy coding!